# Razor views included as Embedded Resource not found after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, publish, embedded-resource

I have added some razor views as embedded resources to my asp.net core 2 project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="Mail\Notifications\**\*.cshtml" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Mail\Notifications\**\*.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I render the views using [RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs):

I also added EmbeddedFileProvider to ServiceCollection in startup.cs:

```
var embeddedProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Program).Assembly); //needed for mailtemplates
var compositeProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(embeddedProvider);
services.AddSingleton(compositeProvider);
```

It works when I run project locally in IIS Express or as Console Application, but when I publish it, the views are not found.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view
>   '~/Mail/Notifications/SubFolder/MyView.cshtml'.
>   The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Mail/Notifications/SubFolder/MyView.cshtml

Comment: That's because [views are precompiled by default in ASP.NET Core 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: Yes, it is, but how to make it work with precompiled view?